# Will OpenStack's Folsom release be supported on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openstack

OpenStack Essex is the version of OpenStack being placed on the current LTS of Ubuntu, but it doesn't include Quantum which has some great networking improvements for OpenStack. This is coming in the Folsom version, but 12.04 currently has Essex. What is an admin wanting folsum and LTS to do in the mean time?

Answer (score 0):

From Canonical whitepaper "What's New Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS"

> Dual lifecycle support policy for OpenStack in Ubuntu Cloud
>
> 1. Stay with the shipped version of OpenStack (Essex) and remain with it for the full life of the LTS.
>
> As per the Ubuntu LTS policy, we commit to maintaining and supporting the Essex release for five years. The interim releases will also ship the Essex version of OpenStack, along with any bug fixes or security updates made available since its release.
>
> 2. Get access to the latest OpenStack releases via Canonical's Ubuntu Cloud archive.
>
> Alternatively, you can elect to enable this archive, and install newer releases of OpenStack (and its dependencies) as they become available, until the next Ubuntu LTS release (in April 2014). This is ideal for users who want to keep up with the latest innovations from Canonical and the OpenStack community.

So if you use Ubuntu Cloud Archive yes, Folsom and other OpenStack releases will be available to LTS.

More info about Ubuntu Cloud Archive can be found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive

and according to this page, the archive isn't up and running yet, but is nearly complete.
https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/servercloud-q-cloud-archive